# Constructor not found for String

Tags: c#, arrays, propertygrid

If I have an object in a property grid containing a `List<string[]>` or `Dictionary<string,string[]>`(using [GenericDictionaryEditor](http://gendictedit.codeplex.com/)), when I click on the detail beside the property and click add, a message pops up saying that no constructor can be found (for the list) or no parameterless constructor found (for the dictionary). I don't understand editors or the property grid really, and any help would be appreciated.

```
[DataMember(Name="FolderPaths")]
[ReadOnly(false)]
[Description("List of folder paths")]
[Editor(typeof(Wexman.Design.GenericDictionaryEditor<string, string[]>), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[Wexman.Design.GenericDictionaryEditor(Title="Folder Paths")]
public Dictionary<string, string[]> FolderPaths { get; set; }
```

This one says constructor not found for System.string[].

```
[DataMember(Name="FolderPaths")]
[ReadOnly(false)]
[Description("List of folder paths")]
public List<string[]> FolderPaths { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why do you have a list of string arrays for paths? It would seem that a simple `List<string>` would work. Does a folder path have multiple paths or something? I'm assuming the reason you get the error is because a `string[]` does not have a constructor like `string[] x = new string[]()`...

Comment: That's what I'm guessing too. Yes, a path will have multiple paths.

Comment: Might have to make a custom type, like a `FolderPath` type that can have a default constructor and then set the paths using get/set accessors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to register a [TypeDescriptionProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider.aspx) for the `string[]` type. Here is the sample code (you need to register this at the beginning of your program, before displaying any property grid):

```
...
TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new StringArrayDescriptionProvider(), typeof(string[]));
...
```

And here is the `StringArrayDescriptionProvider` code:

```
public class StringArrayDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    private static TypeDescriptionProvider _baseProvider;

    static StringArrayDescriptionProvider()
    {
       // get default metadata
        _baseProvider = TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(string[]));
    }

    public override object CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type objectType, Type[] argTypes, object[] args)
    {
        // this is were we define create the instance
        // NB: .NET could do this IMHO...
        return Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string), 0);
    }

    public override IDictionary GetCache(object instance)
    {
        return _baseProvider.GetCache(instance);
    }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetExtendedTypeDescriptor(object instance)
    {
        return _baseProvider.GetExtendedTypeDescriptor(instance);
    }

    public override string GetFullComponentName(object component)
    {
        return _baseProvider.GetFullComponentName(component);
    }

    public override Type GetReflectionType(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        return _baseProvider.GetReflectionType(objectType, instance);
    }

    public override Type GetRuntimeType(Type reflectionType)
    {
        return _baseProvider.GetRuntimeType(reflectionType);
    }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        return _baseProvider.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance);
    }

    public override bool IsSupportedType(Type type)
    {
        return _baseProvider.IsSupportedType(type);
    }
}
```

This is how it will look:
[image]

Comment: Event better, you could modify it for any array type. `objectType.GetElementType()`. You can't do `TypeDescripter.AddProvider( ... , typeof(Array));` because for some reason this results in a StackOverflow Exception.

Comment: yeah I thought about it but the final "string collection editor" only exist for the string type, so it's not so useful. Plus I don't like the idea of tweaking the whole system - side effects :-)

Comment: Oh, Hah. I don't think I tested the string collection editor. :D