# c# UserControl property - setting list of string for custom property - List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, custom-controls

After spending log of time i am not able to solve my problem.

I have List in UserControl i am not able to bind it with custom property at design time.
[Here is Design Screenshot with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEMa2.png)

```
public partial class TagListControl : UserControl
{
    private HashSet<string> _tags;
    private List<string> _Tags;
    //[Browsable(false)] // Hiding this Because It's Not working in
    //[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public List<string> Tags
    {
        get {
            _Tags = _tags.ToList();
            return _Tags; 
        }
        set {
            value = value ?? new List<string>();
            _Tags = value; 
            value.ForEach(x =>
            {
                string[] Tags = x.Split(',');
                foreach (string Tag in Tags)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Tag))
                    {
                        _tags.Add(Tag.Trim());
                    }
                }
                _tags.Add(x);
            });
        }
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public bool AllowMultipleTags
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int Count
    {
        get { return _tags.Count; }
    }

    public TagListControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _tags = new HashSet<string>();
    }

.....

}
```

Can someone explain to me how to get the designer to give the user the string list as the possible values? They can add list of strings as the value one by one.

Comment: Have you looked over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30525790/3026017)? It seems to be similar

Comment: i want user control to store them and automatically use them at run time. i am trying to automate some process using those values at user control level rather than accessing them at From level coding.